# Regex to replace asterisk characters with html bold tag

Tags: objective-c, regex

Does anyone have a good regex to do this? For example:

```
This is *an* example
```

should become

```
This is <b>an</b> example
```

I need to run this in Objective C, but I can probably work that bit out on my own. It's the regex that's giving me trouble (so rusty...). Here's what I have so far:

```
s/\*([0-9a-zA-Z ])\*/<b>$1<\/b>/g
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? Thanks :)

EDIT: Thanks for the answer :) If anyone is wondering what this looks like in Objective-C, using RegexKitLite:

```
NSString *textWithBoldTags = [inputText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"\\*([0-9a-zA-Z ]+?)\\*" withString:@"<b>$1<\\/b>"];
```

EDIT AGAIN: Actually, to encompass more characters for bolding I changed it to this:

```
NSString *textWithBoldTags = [inputText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"\\*([^\\*]+?)\\*" withString:@"<b>$1<\\/b>"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only matching one character between the `*`s.  Try this:

```
s/\*([0-9a-zA-Z ]*?)\*/<b>$1<\/b>/g
```

or to ensure there's at least one character between the `*`s:

```
s/\*([0-9a-zA-Z ]+?)\*/<b>$1<\/b>/g
```

Comment: + might be better than * in this case.  Unless you want "**" to turn into "<b></b>"

Comment: @Nemo @Andrew Cooper - wasn't paying attention to the replace. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I was two characters out? Damn regex *shakes fist*

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just do `\*([^*]+)\*` and replace it with `<b>$1</b>` ?

Comment: For non-JavaScripters like me: `s.replace(/\*([^*]+?)\*/g, "<b>$1<\/b>");`

Comment: For PHP-scripters: 
       $withBTag = preg_replace('/\*([^*]+?)\*/', '<b>$1</b>', $beforeBTag);

Comment: c#: Regex.Replace(s, @"\*([^*]+?)\*", @"<b>$1</b>")

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a slightly more complex version that ensures the asterisk is always at the boundary so it ignores hanging star characters:

```regex
/\*([^\s][^\*]+?[^\s])\*/
```

---

**[Test phrases](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=110225) with which it works and doesn't:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one regexp works for me (JavaScript)

```
x.match(/\B\*[^*]+\*\B/g)
```

Comment: That works great for me. But I don't understand why \B works instead of \b.